# How do I shortcut and not type "python"?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell, bin

RIght now, I type "python myfile.py" to run it.

How can I type "py myfile.py" to run it? 
Or better, do this ./myfile.py?

Any tips?

Answer (score 10):

You can add this as the first line of your python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Which will allow you to run your script as:

```
./myfile.py
```

But you must make sure you make your python script executable:

```
chmod +x myfile.py
```

Comment: And if you want to skip adding the `./` place the script somewhere in your path.  For extra points rename the file and skip adding the `.py` extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
alias py='python'
```